# How to open a protected workbook from VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

How to open a protected workbook(with password) from VBA code ? 
I already try this instruction

`Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\file.xls", ReadOnly:=False, Password:="semsem"`
And it doesn't work.
Is there any suggestion about this Problem?
Note: I use  EXcel2007.

Comment: Does it return an error message? Is the password case sensitive?

Comment: it returns this message:  `runtime error '50289 '

not perform this operation as the file is protected`

Comment: The password was case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

In the vba project did you protect the project from viewing? If so I don't think this will be achievable as the project needs to be physically unprotected if you are wanting to do any code changes. This doesn't help from a vba programming point but from a user tamper free perspective it does.

1. If you do not intend on editing the code I can only suggest you leave the password out.
2. If you intend to alter the code I can only suggest you leave the project unprotected and try to protect the file another way.
3. **Untested** but an idea would be to programmatically create a sheet with the new code in it and copy this sheet into this workbook.

Not much help but the only answer I can offer.

**To manually remove the protection:**

1. If this is a once off, double click the project and enter the password and once finished, saved and closed the project will keep this protection.
   [image: http://www.allaboutvba.vbapasswordremover.net/images/screen/protect-excelrun10.gif]
2. Or if it's to be permanent then right click the project>project properties>protection and uncheck  lock project for viewing.
   [image: http://www.allaboutvba.vbapasswordremover.net/images/screen/protect-excellock8.gif]

Images from [All About VBA](http://www.allaboutvba.vbapasswordremover.net/protect-excel-vba-file.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't know how it protected and when i enter on tools->properties of VBA Project-> protection  i find the password.

Comment: This means the project is protected but only from code changes. The `Password:=""` will not unprotect this it will only unprotect the workbook similarly to using the Review Tab in the application.

Comment: My apologies for the site but it's the best one... [Protect and Unprotect a Workbook](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-protect-an-excel-2007-workbook.navId-323068.html) is what this `Password` is for.

Comment: Is there any solution to unprotect it automatically(by VB code) or to exceed the autentification  step ?

Comment: Simply uncheck the protect from viewing option.

Comment: The password doesn't change frequently but we have to keep it . The goal is to automate access to exel file.

Answer (score 1):

If a Workbook is password protected, it can be opened using VBA. 
But, If a VBA Macro is Password Protected, It cannot be opened or controlled from VBA. For security purpose this is not allowed.

One alternate option would be to pass KeyPress events to enter the password.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\file.xlsx", Password:="semsem"
```

Comment: check your file extention xls or xlsx

Comment: then try the following   Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\file.xls", Password:="semsem"